# How to union two sorted vectors and combine overlapping elements?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, vector, set

Let

```
typedef pair<int, double> Element;
```

I then have two vectors:

```
vector<Element> A, B;
```

These vectors are sorted by the integer in `Element.first`. I want to get a third vector, `C`, which is the union of `A` and `B`. This sounds like [set_union](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/), but I need different behavior when `A[i].first == B[j].first`. `set_union` will simply choose one of the source elements to include in `C`, but I need the result to "combine" the two elements instead. In other words, something like this:

```
C[k].first = A[i].first; // == B[j].first.  set_union does this
C[k].second = A[i].second + B[j].second; // set_union does NOT do this.
```

I'm interested if this is possible using the standard library (or something like Boost). The code to do this manually is not particularly complicated, but I'd like to not re-invent the wheel.

The only other related operation I can find is [merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/). It doesn't merge elements either, and would involve another combining pass.

Comment: `std::merge` can do it with a very clever output iterator, but I think a new algorithm would be better

Comment: @MooingDuck are you thinking of something like `back_inserter` but it checks if the new element is the same as the previous one?

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's good thinking. And since Boost is on the table, that output iterator can be made quite easily via [`function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html)

Comment: @MooingDuck But `merge` is only going to pass one element at a time (from either set, depending on the comparison result) to the output iterator. So the iterator would never see both equal elements together to be able to combine them.

Comment: I beg to differ... the aim here is misguided, and any "clever" application of Standard algorithms and fancy iterators is going to be slower to write, just as verbose and more convoluted than the blindingly obvious looping approach in the style of Alex's answer.

Comment: @Praetorian: If you make an iterator which holds a reference to a container, it can look at the last element of that container and compare it to the one being passed, and decide if it should push the new element onto the end of the container, or combine it with the previous one.

Comment: @Benjamin That would work, I was thinking along similar lines of having the iterator somehow keep track of previously inserted elements, missed the fact that you only need access to the last. But if you had to jump through so many hoops to get `std::merge` to do what you want, I'd side with TonyD that writing a custom algorithm is the way to go.

Comment: Ok - I'd not appreciated how nicely `boost::function_output_iterator` fits this problem... agree that it's a good solution with boost on the table.  (Without that, having to write an iterator that returns a proxy to capture the assignment just wasn't worth the fuss....)

Comment: @Benjamin I take that back. I wrote my own [custom merge](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59cc5a1b64e5c529) to see if it was any better, and I prefer the solution below.

Comment: I think that the OP's operation is better known as "Reduce" as in "Map-Reduce", where the "Reduce" is just "add up the values".

Comment: @Yakk, no this operation is better known as sparse vector addition. Reduce would be like sum or min/max, something that reduces the entire vector into a single value. In my case the only reducing going on is that `+`. If you want to use the MapReduce analogy, there are `set_intersection(A, B).size()` Reduces.

Comment: @adam reduce in map reduce operates on elements with identical keys, not all elements.

Comment: @Yakk yes, but getting the elements with identical keys together is the hard part, not the reduction (I call it `+` here). The term "Reduce" does not describe my whole problem. MapReduce could be used to solve it, but the two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the use of `std::merge` with `boost::function_output_iterator` is pretty clean.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

/* Convenience type alias for our element. */
using Elem = std::pair<int, double>;

/* Convenience type alias for the container of our elements. */
using Elems = std::vector<Elem>;

/* Our appender that will be created with boost::function_output_iterator. */
class Appender {
  public:

  /* Cache the reference to our container. */
  Appender(Elems &elems) : elems_(elems) {}

  /* Conditionally modify or append elements. */
  void operator()(const Elem &elem) const {
    if (!elems_.empty() && elems_.back().first == elem.first) {
      elems_.back().second += elem.second;
      return;
    }  // if
    elems_.push_back(elem);
  }

  private:

  /* Reference to our container. */      
  Elems &elems_;

};  // Appender

int main() {
  // Sample data.
  Elems lhs {{1, 2.3}, {2, 3}, {5, 3.4}};
  Elems rhs {{1, 1.3}, {3, 5.5}, {4, 2.2}};
  Elems result;
  // Merge and use appender to append elements.
  std::merge(std::begin(lhs),
             std::end(lhs),
             std::begin(rhs),
             std::end(rhs),
             boost::make_function_output_iterator(Appender(result)));
  // Print result.
  for (const auto &elem : result) {
    std::cout << elem.first << ' ' << elem.second << std::endl;
  }  // for
}
```

Prints:

```
1 3.6
2 3
3 5.5
4 2.2
5 3.4
```

Note. The use of [function_output_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) was suggested by [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation with a standalone generic algorithm `merge_elements`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template <typename LInput, typename RInput, typename Output>
Output merge_elements(LInput lbegin, LInput lend,
                      RInput rbegin, RInput rend,
                      Output out) {
    while(true) {
        if (lbegin == lend) {
            return std::copy(rbegin, rend, out);
        }

        if (rbegin == rend) {
            return std::copy(lbegin, lend, out);
        }

        if (lbegin->first < rbegin->first) {
            *out++ = *lbegin++;
        } else if (rbegin->first < lbegin->first) {
            *out++ = *rbegin++;
        } else {
            *out++ = std::make_pair(lbegin->first, lbegin->second + rbegin->second);
            ++lbegin;
            ++rbegin;
        }
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

/* Convenience type alias for our element. */
using Elem = std::pair<int, double>;

/* Convenience type alias for the container of our elements. */
using Elems = std::vector<Elem>;

int main() {
  // Sample data.
  Elems lhs {{1, 2.3}, {2, 3}, {5, 3.4}};
  Elems rhs {{1, 1.3}, {3, 5.5}, {4, 2.2}};
  Elems result;
  // Merge and use appender to append elements.
  merge_elements(std::begin(lhs),
                 std::end(lhs),
                 std::begin(rhs),
                 std::end(rhs),
                 std::back_inserter(result));
  // Print result.
  for (const auto &elem : result) {
    std::cout << elem.first << ' ' << elem.second << std::endl;
  }  // for
}
```

It doesn't require boost, but has almost exactly the same total line count as mpark's boost solution. Interestingly, this algorithm is generic enough to work unchanged with a `std::map<int,double>` as well as `std::vector<std::pair<int,double>>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

/* Convenience type alias for the container of our elements. */
using Elems = std::map<int, double>;

int main() {
  // Sample data.
  Elems lhs {{1, 2.3}, {2, 3}, {5, 3.4}};
  Elems rhs {{1, 1.3}, {3, 5.5}, {4, 2.2}};
  Elems result;
  // Merge and use appender to append elements.
  merge_elements(std::begin(lhs),
                 std::end(lhs),
                 std::begin(rhs),
                 std::end(rhs),
                 std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
  // Print result.
  for (const auto &elem : result) {
    std::cout << elem.first << ' ' << elem.second << std::endl;
  }  // for
}
```